# mysqli php search form blank

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am learning PHP and MySQL for a small project that I am involved in, I am at a point where I am trying to make a search feature to search my database. When I try to load my page it comes up blank. Below is is my code for my search.php page.

```
<?php
$mysqli_db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'train');


$result_tb = "";
if (!empty($_POST['SEARCH']) && !empty($_POST['search_value']) {

   $e = $_POST['search_value'];

   $query = 'SELECT * FROM train2015 WHERE ' .
       "name LIKE '%$e%'";

$query_result = $mysqli_db->query($query);

$result_tb = '<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">';
while ($rows = $query_result->fetch_assoc()) {
  foreach ($rows as $k => $v) {
     $result_tb .= '<tr><td>' . $k . '</td><td>' . $v . '</td></tr>';
   }
}
$result_tb .='</table>';

$mysqli_db->close();
}
?>
 <html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
     <table>
        <tr>
           <td>
              <input type="text" name="search_value" size="30" maxlength="30"/>
           </td>
           <td>
              <input type="submit" name="SEARCH" value="Search"/>
           </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
  </form>
  <?php echo $result_tb; ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Thank for your help.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['SEARCH'])` is better.

Comment: Just FYI, you are using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` unsafely use it like this:
`<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];) ?>`

Comment: You're also missing a bracket for `if (!empty($_POST['SEARCH']) && !empty($_POST['search_value'])` - >>> http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have told you that and signaled a parse error.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, I've changed my if statement toif (isset($_POST['SEARCH'])) && !empty($_POST['search_value']) , Should I change the second !empty to isset? Seems like i'm still missing something.

Comment: It's `if(!empty($_POST['SEARCH']) && !empty($_POST['search_value']))` <= bracket goes here, and not the way you have it in your comment. and yes, use `isset()` for the submit button. `if(isset($_POST['SEARCH']) && !empty($_POST['search_value']))`

Comment: Check if your SQL search is actually generating results. Maybe also view page source to see if you're generating HTML output.

Comment: If and when what I said above worked ^ which I'm confident it will, you can delete the question, unless you really really want it answered.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for your help Fred!  I appreciate the patience that you have with us new programmers.

Comment: You're welcome Lance. Would you like me to post it as an answer then? which you can mark as solved.

Comment: I'll keep this around for reference for atleast myself and maybe someone else looking to create a search function with mysql and php. Thanks again.

Comment: If you could post it as an answer that would be great!

Comment: It has been done Lance, *cheers*

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a bracket at the end of your conditional statement, which should read as:

```
if (!empty($_POST['SEARCH']) && !empty($_POST['search_value']))
                                                              ^ right there
```

However, it's best using `isset()` for your submit button, therefore do:

```
if(isset($_POST['SEARCH']) && !empty($_POST['search_value']))
```

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

which would have signaled a parse error.

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Plus, as mentioned in comments, it's best and safer to use:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];) ?>
```

instead of what you're presently using in your form.

---

As a sidenote:

You should consider looking into [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.